# SQL Server : incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: python, sql, syntax

I've successfully connected to my server and need to select the data in my SQL Server table from Python.

However, I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

whenever I try running the code.

This current code is a copy of another code that is working 100%, so I do not know why it is not working. The only difference from the working code and the current code is that I am pulling data from a different table.

Table that works is `PC030_NG_Count`, table that causes the error is `PB040_NG_Count`.

When I switch from `PB040_NG_Count` to `PC030_NG_Count`, there's no more error.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT CAST(read_at_2 AS datetime),cell,station," +
               " CAST(Color_NG AS float)/NULLIF(Total_Production,0)," +
               " CAST(Angle_NG AS float)/NULLIF(Total_Production,0)," +
               " CAST(ID_NG AS float)/NULLIF(Total_Production,0)," +
               " CAST(OD_NG AS float)/NULLIF(Total_Production,0)," +
               " CAST(Height_NG AS float)/NULLIF(Total_Production,0)" +
               " FROM PB040_NG_Count" +
               " WHERE read_at_2 BETWEEN '" + query_start_time + "'" +
               " AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
               " ORDER BY read_at_2 ASC")
```

Comment: to me, doesn't look like MS SQL. Please tag the database you're using and fix the title.

Comment: and btw, you'll get an error with this line :   CAST(Color_NG AS float)/NULLIF(Total_Production,0)     if Total_Production is NULL, then you get a division by 0 error

Comment: It is MS SQL, I am inserting SQL command strings from python to the MS SQL. I've been able to do it on other tables but some how it isn't retrieving the data from the table I want because of the "incorrect syntax error near from"

Comment: Thank you, I will fix that and try

Comment: @brandysriruk you have `\`` in your code, was that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, no that wasn't in the code. This is my first time asking a question on here so that was my mistake when transferring the code into here. I'll edit it now.

Comment: honestly, can't find what's the problem. try this :   select 1 from pb040_ng_count where read_at_2 between ....    just to make sure if the problem is before the from clause.  if it works, then back to your query, comment all fields and uncomment one field at a time and execute it until the query failed.  Then, you'll where to look

Comment: @MLeblanc you have your NULLIF and ISNULL confused. The code pattern `x/NULLIF(y,0)` is used precisely to *avoid* a div/0. NULLIF converts a divisor of 0 to NULL producing a NULL result not a div/0. You might be confusing SQLS NULLIF with MySQL IFNULL (in SQLS: ISNULL)

Comment: 1) **The error posted won’t appear or go away by _just_ changing an identifier that is not reserved.** Maybe there is an invisible character? If not, I suspect it’s not ‘accurately reported’, _provided a minimal example, that can run in SSMS, without string building_; 2) This _syntax error_ has nothing to do with runtime behavior.

Comment: @brandyriruk I get the feeling you're changing something else too, like the columns list when yoinswap the table name over. Perhaps you're leaving a comma on the column so you're writing (effectively) `SELECT a,b, FROM ...`

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for your input and everyone else's. I will be back at work tomorrow, so I will check for the extra comma and will update you guys on what happens.

Comment: @CaiusJard you're right, i read too quick

Comment: @brandyriruk if you use three `"` to start your python string then things like new lines don't break the string. It means you don't have to have all this string concat `"SELECT"+" column "+" FROM"` to build your life g sql string- all that extra garbage means you're more likely to make a syntax error in the sql.

Comment: @MLeblanc Thank you for your input. I went line by line as you recommended and found out that the error only pops up when I was calling for less than 8 columns. So it was a difference in columns between the 2 tables. 

Thank you to everyone else's response also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you **sure** there is no difference in the column names/definitions between tables PC030_NG_Count and PB040_NG_Count?

Comment: Thank you for your response and you were right. There was a difference is number of columns. PC030_NG_Count has 8 columns and PB040_NG_Count has 7 columns. Thank you. Thank you.